# Getting this error when I use IBM Watson Tone Analyzer API. How can I resolve this?

Tags: python, error-handling, ibm-watson

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.eu-gb.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com', port=443):
    Max retries exceeded with url:
        /instances/76db955a-ebbb-46c9-a9ca-121542253a0c/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&sentences=true
    (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x05533928>:
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))`
```

The output console shows a part of the output I am getting while printing at runtime and then this max retries exceeded error message pops up. Please revert back as soon as possible.

Comment: When I visit [that URL](https://api.eu-gb.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/76db955a-ebbb-46c9-a9ca-121542253a0c/v3/tone) it asks for a username and password.

Comment: Please show the code that generated the error.